# REINFORCE algorithm

Tags: python, pytorch, reinforcement-learning

Hello I have been trying to implement the reinforce algorithm as it is presented in Introduction to Reinforcement learning by sutton and barto. After many hours of trying I cant figure out why my algorithm is not working, I feel like my implementation is correct.

The agent is not learning as printing the cumulative reward over an episode there is no improvement on the score achieved after a series of episodes

I would really be grateful for some help!

```
#Import libraries
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.nn.functional as F
import gym
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from torch.distributions import Categorical

class Actor(nn.Module):
    
    """
    Use a ANN to construct a parameterized policy

    Input layer: observation space length
    First hidden layer: 128
    ReLU activation
    second hidden layer: 256
    ReLU activation
    Output layer: action space length
    Softmax activation
    """
    
    def __init__(self, state_size, action_size):
        super(Actor, self).__init__()
        self.state_size = state_size
        self.action_size = action_size
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(self.state_size,64)
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(64, self.action_size)
        
        
    def forward(self,state):
        x = F.relu(self.linear1(state))
        x = self.linear2(x)
        x = F.softmax(x, dim=-1)
        return x
    
    def select_action(self,state):
        
        #convert state to float tensor, add 1 dimension, allocate tensor on device
        state = torch.from_numpy(state).float().unsqueeze(0).to(device)
        action_probs = self.forward(state)
        #sample an action using the probability distribution
        dist = Categorical(action_probs)
        action = dist.sample()
        
        return action.item(), dist.log_prob(action)
    
    

device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu" #Set device
episodes = 1000
step = 0
lr = 0.005
gamma = 0.9999
env = gym.make('CartPole-v0') # import cartpole environment
env.seed(0)
"""
The cartpole environment has an observation space of length 4
1) Cart Position, 2) Cart Velocity, 3) Pole Angle, 4) Pole Angular Velocity

The action space is of length two
1) Push cart to the left, Push cart to the right
"""
state_size = env.observation_space.shape[0]
action_size = env.action_space.n
actor = Actor(state_size, action_size).to(device)
optimizer_actor = optim.Adam(actor.parameters(), lr = lr) # import optimizer

for i in range(episodes):
    #Loop forever

    state = env.reset() # Initialize S
    cumulative_reward = 0
    done = False
    actions,states, rewards = [], [], []
    #print(1)
    while not done:
        # Generate episode S0, A0, R1,.. ,S_{T-1}, A_{T-1},RT, following pi(·|·, theta)
        
        #get action and log probability
        action, logp = actor.select_action(state)
        
        state, reward, done, _ = env.step(action) #take action in environment
        rewards.append(reward)
        actions.append(action)
        states.append(state)
        cumulative_reward +=reward
        #Store episode trajectory
        
    discounted_returns = []
    for t in range(len(rewards)):
        G = 0.0
        for k, r in enumerate(rewards[t:]):
            G += (gamma**k)*r
        discounted_returns.append(G)
    
    for state, action, G in zip(states, actions, discounted_returns):
        
        
        state = torch.from_numpy(state).float().unsqueeze(0).to(device)
        probs = actor(state)
        dist = Categorical(probs=probs)    
        action = torch.tensor(action, dtype=torch.int).to(device)
        logp = dist.log_prob(action)
        loss = - logp*G
        
        
        optimizer_actor.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer_actor.step()
        
    
    print('Episode {} Score: {:.2f}'.format(i, cumulative_reward))
```

Comment: In addition to the comment by @AKX, please explain what the reinforce algorithm is.  We all don't happen to have access to your text book.  So if you want someone to answer, educate us.